# Using a factory_girl object out of an it block

Tags: rspec, scope, factory-bot

I want to loop over an array of objects that are built by factory_girl outside of an `it` block.

Example:

```
before :each do
  @array = build(:super_cool_array_of_objects)
end

context 'I want access to @array here' do

  @array.each do |item|
    it 'tests item for some interesting things' do
      item.should be_true # my test is more complicated than this
    end
  end

end
```

But when I do this, I get an error that `@array` is `nil` since the `before :each` hasn't been evaluated yet. I've tried setting `@array` in a `let` and `let!` but haven't had any success.

Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that what you want to do is isolate the logic of building something using FactoryGirl in a method and then using that to define various Rspec examples.

Here's a technique of doing so by creating a global method.

```
def how_about_a_method
  2.times.map { FactoryGirl.build(:foo) }
end

describe 'lucys question' do
  context 'accessing something' do
    how_about_a_method.each do |item|
      it 'should have an item' do
        expect(item).to be
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Note that you'll need to use `FactoryGirl.build` because in your spec_helper you've specified to include the FactoryGirl syntax methods with `config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods` but in this global method you're not in an RSpec class anymore so FactoryGirl hasn't been included. I tend to prefer to not include FactoryGirl as it specifies in the documentation, but will instead always reference FactoryGirl explicitly as I have done in the method here.

A more interesting question is "Why is `@array` nil?". It helps to understand a little bit about how RSpec works. Inside your `it` block is what is known as an example. This is evaluated in a different scope to the `context` block (which is known as an `ExampleGroup`). Attempting to use result of `before`, `let` or `let!` in the ExampleGroup context doesn't work because they are also evaluated in the Example context, that is the same scope your `it` block is evaluated in.

Obviously a global method is global so you can access it wherever you like.

Personally I think the scoping is the most complicated part of RSpec. I wish it were documented better.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed :) The explanation about `ExampleGroup` vs `Example` context was really helpful - I knew there was something about scoping going on, but couldn't figure out why the `it` blocks were "special". Thanks for clearing it up!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
describe 'something' do
  array = [1,2,3]
  context 'access array here' do
    array.each do |item|
      it 'tests item for some interesting things' do
        item.should be_true # my test is more complicated than this
      end
    end
  end
end
```

FactoryGirl version:

You can drop `FactoryGirl.build(...)` as a replacement expression to `[1,2,3]`.

```
gem 'factory_girl'
require 'factory_girl'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :super_cool_array_of_objects, class: Array do
    initialize_with { [1,2,3] }
  end
end

describe 'something' do
  context 'access array here' do
    FactoryGirl.build(:super_cool_array_of_objects).each do |item|
      it "tests item #{item} for some interesting things" do
        item.should be_true # my test is more complicated than this
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, I agree that would work. But you are hard coding your `array` variable. I want mine to come from factory_girl. I'm confused about when my `@array` actually gets created, and how to access it outside of an `it` block, since it relies on whatever factory_girl uses to build new objects. (My `@array` is an array of objects - edited for clarity.)

Comment: Replacing `array` with `FactoryGirl.build` is a straight substitution of one expression with another. You can think of RSpec scopes much like Plain Old Ruby Objects: Inside `it` and `each` blocks is a bit like being inside an instance method, while outside `it` and `each` is akin to writing code inside a `class` or `module` but outside a method.

Comment: Yep, it was the `FactoryGirl.build` I was missing. I thought I could just call a normal `build` and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working. Thanks for the explanation about the scoping being like `class`/`module` vs. method :)